# AWS Cognito - Create a user via API Endpoint in Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Does anybody know if I can make a request to create or a sign up a user in AWS Cognito user pool?

For example, something like below is to display the login screen.
But is there a POST request or endpoint I can call to create a user?

I tried looking through their documentation but no look finding anything concrete.

Keep in mind, if it possible I would like to populate a value for a custom attribute I created.
This is the main reason why I am looking for an endpoint because I cannot seem to find a way to populate the value for a custom attribute via the AWS interface.

So technically I do not need an endpoint if it is possible to populate a custom attribute per user in AWS.

```
GET https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?
response_type=code&
client_id=ad398u21ijw3s9w3939&
redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/redirect_uri&
state=STATE&
scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you need is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html. As far as I'm aware, there is no way to prepopulate the attribute on the Cognito hosted UI. You did not specify what programming language you are using, but at the bottom of the page there are links to documentation with examples for different SDKs. The difference between these two approaches is discussed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html. So in this case, AdminCreateUser corresponds to option 3 and SignUp to option 1. The difference is mainly in whether or not the user will receive an invite. Also, for AdminCreateUser Cognito will generate a temporary password and require user to enter a new password the first time they log in.

Comment: Yeah, a little trial and error got me where I want with the help of those links.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Body**

```
  {
   "ClientId": "test",
   "Password": "Qwerty123",
   "UserAttributes": [
    {
        "Name": "email",
        "Value": "test@test.com"
    }
],
  "Username": "test@test.com"
}
```

**Headers**

[image]

**URL**

POST `https://cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1`

Comment: @Aleksander Zoric this was exactly the answer I was looking for , but I get "Unable to verify secret hash for client <clientId>" in response , also could you pls specify the documentation for the above API

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue @aleksandar-zoric ? I just keep getting bad request with this example.

Comment: @NahuelGonzalez Updated answer above.  Even the previous answer should have worked but just added a screenshot with my current headers and the POST URL. This works for me as is.